# @RequestBody attribute is empty after ajax POST method call

Tags: ajax, spring-mvc, jackson

I am trying to send ajax POST request to server and to retrieve response.
My problem is that when I submit form, my @RequestBody param is empty.
I followed this tutorial and did the same as that guy did. http://www.mkyong.com/spring-mvc/spring-4-mvc-ajax-hello-world-example/

Relevant part of the code:
Controller:

```
@JsonView(Views.Public.class)
    @RequestMapping(value = "searchEvents", method = RequestMethod.POST, produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE, consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    @ResponseBody
    public ModelAndView findEvents(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, @RequestBody EventFilterBean eventFilterBean) {
        ///
    }
```

index.jsp

```
var search = {}
        search["eventName"] = $("#eventName").val();

        $.ajax({
            type : "POST",
            contentType : "application/json",
            url : "searchEvents",
            data : JSON.stringify(search),
            dataType : 'json',
            timeout : 100000
        });
```

in pom.xml I added

```
            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
                <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
                <version>2.9.0.pr3</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
                <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
                <version>2.9.0.pr3</version>
            </dependency>
```

I tried to find solution on google but I couldn't. Thank you for help in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I installed fiddler and conluded that $("#eventName").val(); doesn't give me String which I wanted. When I changed search["eventName"] = $("#eventName").val(); to search["eventName"] = "Some hardcoded string"; it works. It works even without @JsonView(Views.Public.class)

Answer (score 0):

According to:

```
    var search = {}
    search["eventName"] = $("#eventName").val();

    $.ajax({
        type : "POST",
        contentType : "application/json",
        url : "searchEvents",
        data : JSON.stringify(search),
        dataType : 'json',
        timeout : 100000
    });
```

You're sending JSON in String format, so the first thing to do is to put `@RequestBody` annotation on String parameter.

Secondly, add `/` to your route value.

Third, if you're using Ajax you can't return ModelAndView, you need to return an HTTP message which contains inside it your response.

Like this:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/searchEvents", method = RequestMethod.POST, consumes = "application/json", produces="application/json")
    @ResponseBody
    public ResponseEntity<String> findEvents(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, @RequestBody String eventFilterBean) {
        ///
    }
```

Comment: Hello, thank you very much for answer. I agree for return value, but that is not my problem right now. You can see in the tutorial that it is possible to pass my own custom class as param and in that tutorial that works.As I understood from tutorial I should include jackson on classpath and jackson should be capable to resolve and to match eventName field from json to my eventName string in custom class.